# Access from Win 7 inside Virtualbox to EXTERNAL Samba Ser

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, virtualbox, samba

even after reading two days of information I havn't found a solution for my problem. 
I hope You can help me.

I'm running Win 7 inside in a VirtualBox. The Virtualbox itself is running on an openSuSE Linux installation. Then I have my network server running as well openSuSE. The network server is not on the same hardware as the Virtualbox. It's a second hardware.

Now I want to connect from my Win 7 to the Samba shares on the network server. Since the server is not the same hardware as the PC for the virtualbox I can not use those shared folders from Virtualbox.

Win 7 in Virtualbox is running fine; I use the default NAT and can go to the internet.
The Samba shares can be seen with an old WinXP notebook, so Samba is okay as well.

If I want to connect from Win 7 to a network only the Win7 and another VBOXSRV server are shown. My Samba server is not there. I added the ports in the forwarding list (137. 138, 139 and 445) but no success.

Win7 guest has the IP 10.0.2.15.
Samba server has the IP 192.168.0.2.
VBox host has the IP !92.168.0.3.

What do I need to do?

Thank for suggestions.

Best regards

Wolfgang

Comment: Is there any good reason you configured the guests NIC to be NAT? If not, try "Bridged".

Comment: I also tried "Brigded" but things did not become better.